DAPR and CosmosDb
Trying to do insert to CosmosDb using DaprClient. Below is code
[HttpPost("saveData")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> SaveData([FromBody] InputMessage message, [FromServices] DaprClient daprClient)
{

    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "partitionKey", "ServiceName" } };

    if (message is null)
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { error = $"The client is null" });

    var state = await daprClient.GetStateEntryAsync<TestModel>(_cosmosStoreName, "ServiceName", metadata: data);


    if (state.Value != null)
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { error = $"The client with id {message.id} already exists" });
    };

    state.Value = new TestModel
    {
        ServiceName = "ServiceName"
    };


    await state.SaveAsync();
    return "Good";
}

PartitionKey is ServiceName. When I run dapr cli, and make request, I get below error
{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Message: {\\\"Errors\\\":[\\\"PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header. Learn more: https:\\\\/\\\\/aka.ms\\\\/CosmosDB\\\\/sql\\\\/errors\\\\/wrong-pk-value\\\"]}\\r\\nActivityId: 6ca949f9-da2a-4fe9-a346-a67196817670

When i trace for log with above activityid in CosmosDb, i see in AzureDiagnostics, for Category PartitionKeyRUConsumption, partitionKey_s as "fanglava-coyote||ServiceName"
So my guess is DAPR is giving out partitionKey like that. What am i doing wrong here? Can you please guide how it need to be implemented?
metadata parameter was added later on, when call by just passing key gave same result.

Created a new container with partitionkey as "partitionKey", and that seem to work. But when running with dapr cli, id is captured as "ocelotdull-throat||72b93714-f87e-4189-a877-351fd4380cf0". Why is it prefixing name? Also adding metadata to change partitionkey doesnt seem to work

id is not the same thing as partitionKey (unless you literally choose /id as your partition key). And you should be specifying a value of a document's partition key when writing, not the field name. As for id value: Seems like Dapr is generating an id for you (which every document needs). Please be sure to edit your question with additional detail - it shouldn't be in comments.

@DavidMakogon Ya obviously id is not partitionkey. why /id, also partitionKey is getting prefixed with Dapr Id, like "fanglava-coyote"? Also please be sure to comment if you know on dapr integration
